# Experience editor ribbon disappear

Tags: experience-editor, azure, cookies, ribbon

When I open a site in experience editor mode, I see the editor ribbon, but after I navigate on the site, the ribbon disappears.
Everything is fine in the local environment, but the error occurs in Azure.

I use Sitecore 9.3.
[image]

In my opinion, the cookies are fine:

[image: cookies]

Has anyone experienced anything similar?

UPDATE:

I've found a related error message in the log files

```
2022-08-04 10:58:48.787 [system]       ERROR (6560) Unhandled Exception: Error while rendering view: '/sitecore/shell/client/Speak/Layouts/Layouts/Speak-Layout.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Error while rendering view: '/sitecore/shell/client/Speak/Layouts/Layouts/Speak-Layout.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').

Source: Sitecore.Mvc
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Error while rendering view: '/sitecore/shell/client/Speak/Layouts/Renderings/Common/PageCodes/PageCode.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').

Source: Sitecore.Mvc
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.RenderPlaceholderCore(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName)
   at ASP._sitecore_shell_client_Speak_Layouts_Layouts_Speak_Layout_cshtml.Execute()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Web.HttpException
Message: Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent.
Source: System.Web
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url, Boolean endResponse, Boolean permanent)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Web.ShellPage.GotoLoginPage(HttpContext httpContext, Boolean returnAfterLogin)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Web.ShellPage.IsLoggedIn(Boolean returnAfterLogin)
   at Sitecore.LaunchPad.LaunchPad.Initialize()
   at ASP._sitecore_shell_client_Speak_Layouts_Renderings_Common_PageCodes_PageCode_cshtml.Execute()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
```

Comment: are you getting any error in browser console?

Comment: No errors in console nor in log files..

Comment: And is it working when you load the page? And then disappear when you are trying to navigate?

Comment: Yes. When I open the experience editor everything works well, but after I navigate e.g. in the menu, the ribbon disappears.

Comment: Did you try to check with a blank page with no rendering? Or you can remove renderings from your existing page and check?

Comment: I have tried. The error is the same. But I found an error message in the log. I've updated the post.

Comment: Why your header is in green? (ignore this comment if you set this color for question only)
Do you use any specific scripts in Tampermonkey? Or maybe Sitecore Author Toolbox? Or maybe you changed Sitecore logic to show the version and change color?

If yes then try to disable it and check again.

Comment: We use different colors in different environments. (DEV, UAT, PROD) :)

Comment: @KrisztianJofoldi Can you check this in your web.config `<add key="role:define" value="ContentManagement" />`

Comment: Also check this article https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/14720/experience-editor-not-working-error-while-rendering-sitecore-shell-cshtml-files

Comment: Can you compare "/sitecore/shell/client/Speak/Layouts/Renderings/Common/PageCodes/PageCode.cshtml" file as well code on Azure vs your local environment may be something is missing or code difference.